# jQuery plugin best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

This is a plugin I wrote a while ago and I'm trying to improve it. Is this the best practice for jQuery plugins? Should I use options for flexibility?

The initial aim was to replicate the syntax for `.fadeIn()` in jQuery.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
/* AnimateCSS - CSS transitions instead of js */
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    // Function-level strict mode syntax
  'use strict';

    $.fn.animateCSS = function (effect, delay, callback) {

        // Return this to maintain chainability
        return this.each(function () {

            // Cache $(this) for speed and compression
            var $this = $(this),
                transitionEnd = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationEnd",
                animated = "animated",
                visibility = "visibility",
                visible = "visible",
                hidden = "hidden";

            // Create a function we can call later
            function run() {
                // Add the animation effect with classes
                $this.addClass( animated + " " + effect);

                // Check if the elemenr has been hidden to start with
                if ($this.css( visibility ) === hidden) {
                    // If it has, show it (after the class has been added)
                    $this.css( visibility, visible);    
                }

                // If the element is hidden
                if ($this.is(":" + hidden)) {
                    // Show it
                    $this.show();
                }

                // Event triggered when the animation has finished
                $this.bind( transitionEnd, function () {
                    // Remove the classes so they can be added again later
                    $this.removeClass(animated + " " + effect);

                    // Add a callback event
                    if (typeof callback === "function") {
                        // Execute the callback
                        callback.call(this);

                        // Unbind the event handlers
                        $this.unbind( transitionEnd );
                    }   
                });   
            }  
            // Check if delay exists or if it"s a callback

            if (!delay || typeof delay === "function") {   
                // If it"s a callback, move it to callback so we can call it later
                callback = delay;    

                // Run the animation (without delay)
                run();
            } else {
                // Start a counter so we can delay the animation if required
                setTimeout( run, delay );
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome code,

- Well named variables, commented and easy tor read
- JsHint.com has nothing on this code
- Use `'use strict'`